# Writing to .xml file error message

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to write to a .xml file. The problem is that when I am writing I am getting the error message: **Cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'**. Now I know that this means that I need to convert the integer to a string, but I am confused on how to do that. The
code that I am using is as follows:

```
  private void GetProperties()
        {
        //CreateNode(everything being referenced. Put text boxes, and drop down boxes here.
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\ForteSenderv2.0\Forte.dat", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

        //Making the code indeted by 2 characters.
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;

        //Making the start element "Table".
        writer.WriteStartElement("Forte_Data_Gatherer_Application");
        //Calling the rst of the .xml file to write.
        CreateNode(Portbx.SelectedIndex, BaudRatebx.SelectedIndex, Databitsbx.SelectedIndex, Paritybx.SelectedIndex, StopBitsbx.SelectedIndex, Handshakingbx.SelectedIndex, writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();

    }
```

The error is firing at `CreateNode(Portbx.SelectedIndex, BaudRatebx.SelectedIndex, Databitsbx.SelectedIndex, Paritybx.SelectedIndex, StopBitsbx.SelectedIndex, Handshakingbx.SelectedIndex, writer);`

Comment: This problem is staring you right in the face.. `look at your Method Signature` HINT `Portbx.SelectedIndex.ToString()` pass in the correct datatype to your method CreateNode and your problem will be fixed

Comment: haha! I can't believe I didn't think of that, I feel dumb now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well like I always say.. it is better to `Feel Dumb than to Be Dumb` LOL you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit cast from an integer to string. Either you need to call `ToString()` on your index arguments:

`CreateNode(Portbx.SelectedIndex.ToString(), ...`

or you need to alter the signature of `CreateNode` to take integers

`CreateNode(int Port, ...`

Comment: The `ToString()` worked. changing the CreateNode method will not work as I need to keep the `writer.WriteString(Port);`

Comment: Why won't changing the method signature work Chase..? I believe that you are not understanding Method Overloading give it a try and I think you will prove yourself wrong.. if you need a type to be of a certain value then before calling and or when you are calling that method and passing in the Params, you can do the conversion at that time.. basic programming

Comment: I understand that, but I need to have the `writer.WriteString()` if I change `string Port` to `int Port` then I cannot use `writer.WriteString()`.

Comment: True. You many want to look at LINQ to XML for an alternative way to write this class as an XML element.

Comment: Using `ToString()` worked just fine. I am on my way now. Haha thank you.